# ios resignFirstResponder of UITextView in cell from accessory toolbar

Tags: ios

I am trying to edit a UITextView inside a cell with a keyboard that preserves the 'return' key for line break & adds a 'cancel' & 'done' button in an accessory toolbar.  Everything looks fine but the 'sender' parameter in the selector is pointing to the UIBarButtonItem and not the UITextView in the cell so the program breaks with an error.  How do I tell the selected cell's UITextView to resignFirstResponder?

```
// cell with accessory toolbar    
if (!cell)
{
        [tableView registerNib: [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
        [cell.textView setDelegate:self];

        UIToolbar* toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
        toolBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered     target:self action:@selector(toolBarCancel:)],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(toolBarDone:)],
                       nil];
        [toolBar sizeToFit];
        cell.textView.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

// selector
- (IBAction) toolBarDone:(id)sender {
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

or

```
[self.view endEditiing:YES];
```

From Apple's Docs:

> This method looks at the current view and its subview hierarchy for
>   the text field that is currently the first responder. If it finds one,
>   it asks that text field to resign as first responder. If the force
>   parameter is set to YES, the text field is never even asked; it is
>   forced to resign.

This is the goto function for making the keyboard drop, no matter what view brought it up.

Comment: Thank you.  One more question:  How do I get the cell.textView.text value now?

Comment: That's a question that can have several different answers depending on context. Post it as a separate question with a copy of your `CustomCell` class.

Comment: I was trying to edit that question off.  I figured it out. Thank you. Method was : CustomCell *cell = [_customTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(rowValue) inSection:(sectionValue)]];